# Postfix-Incrementoperator with ternary expression shows unexpected behavior

Tags: java, expression, ternary

I have a problem understanding this behavior:

My intention is that `numberOfFilesNotFolders` gets incremented by 1.

Asuming that file is not a directory.

case 1:

```
int numberOfFilesNotFolders = 0;
numberOfFilesNotFolders = file.isDirectory() ? numberOfFilesNotFolders : numberOfFilesNotFolders++;
```

`numberOfFilesNotFolders` stays 0

---

case 2:

```
int numberOfFilesNotFolders = 0;
numberOfFilesNotFolders = file.isDirectory() ? numberOfFilesNotFolders : numberOfFilesNotFolders+1;
```

`numberOfActualFilesNotFolders` is incremented and becomes 1

---

What I don't understand is why case 1 does not work. The way I see it, it should work like this:

1. `file.isDirectory()` resolves as false
2. `numberOfFilesNotFolders++` stores the value 0 into `numberOfFilesNotFolders`
3. `numberOfFilesNotFolders++` does the incrementation

step 3. should then change the value of `numberOfFilesNotFolders` to 1, which then should be set.

But actually `numberOfFilesNotFolders` stays 0. And that I don't understand.

If someone could elaborate why it stays 0, that would be great.

greets
tool

Comment: Try again with `++numberOfFilesNotFolders`, you'll see.

Comment: `x = x++` is a bug more often than not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because it´s a post increment? Basicly your statement is getting evaluated as.

```
numberOfFilesNotFolders = numberOfFilesNotFolders
```

here´s the steps that actually happen.

1. `file.isDirectory()` us evaluated as true
2. `numberOfFilesNotFolders++` return the temporary variable of 0 and increments `numberOfFilesNotFolders` by one.
3. you assign the temprary value of the `numberOfFilesNotFolders++` operation to `numberOfFilesNotFolders` and `numberOfFilesNotFolders` is equal to `0` again.

if you change the statement to `++numberOfFilesNotFolders` with a preincrement you would get your expected result.

Otherwise you could also just simply use an if statement instead of using a ternary operator.

Comment: so it is : `numberOfActualFilesNotFoldersTemp  = numberOfActualFilesNotFolders;` and then `numberOfActualFilesNotFolders = numberOfActualFilesNotFolders +1;` and then `numberOfActualFilesNotFolders numberOfActualFilesNotFoldersTemp`

Comment: the last line misses the **=** and the **;**. It is meant to be: `numberOfActualFilesNotFolders = numberOfActualFilesNotFoldersTemp;`